# Tool for Stacking contexts / z-indexes

Tags: html, css, z-index

Is there a tool on firefox or standalone that show me the different stacking contexts (different z-indexes) on a web page?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, firebug shows the computed styles. Hence you can know the stacking contexts.

Comment: I know. I would like a tool that show me graphically the different contexts... for exapmple with different colors